# Twitter Bootstrap collapse only on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a menu with a title *(which will be the trigger to the menu)*. 
I want the menu to collapse only on mobile resolution.
 
On bigger screen, I want this menu to fully show.
I added `hidden-xs` to this menu but this doesn't work.

```
<span class='footer_list' data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#resources">
  Resources
</span>

<ul class="list-unstyled hidden-xs footer-nav" id="resources">
  <li><a class="footer_link" href='#'>Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a class="footer_link" href='#'>Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a class="footer_link" href='#'>Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a class="footer_link" href='#'>Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

The `hidden-xs` disable the toggle so I can't see the menu, even when I click on the title.

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer and accept it for future use

Answer (score -1):

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
 .footer-nav{
    display: block !important;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    overflow: visible !important;
 }
}
```